# Label showing jagged text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, quartz-graphics

I've created a custom button class to be used in my xibs that is basically just a button with a shadow with a label over it. However, the text in the label appears jagged (as though it is not being anti-aliased). Here's my code for the relevant part of the class (it's a very small class that inherits from UIButton).

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self internalInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self internalInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)internalInit {

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:22/255.0 green:72/255.0 blue:143/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(floorf(frame.origin.x), floorf(frame.origin.y));
    //self.frame = CGRectIntegral(frame);
    frame = self.titleLabel.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(floorf(frame.origin.x), floorf(frame.origin.y));
    //self.titleLabel.frame = CGRectIntegral(frame);
    // Shadow
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1.5);
    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    self.layer.shadowPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds] CGPath];

    // Corner
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
}
```

I've tried troubleshooting the issue and I've found that this can occur when the origin for the label or the button is set at a non-integer value. However, I've checked the absolute value for both the button and the pixel and they are both set to integer values. I haven't been able to figure out what else could be going wrong and I cannot find any others who have had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when jaggies happen it's because the same view is being drawn multiple times over itself. Did you confirm this view is only being drawn once?